# how to implement an interface with different type best practice

Tags: c#

according to the clean architecture,each layer should have its own model(its better not to send the same model in other services),I will give you an example:

In my API leyer i receive a list as a viewmodel:

```
public class ApiLayerViewModel
{
    public string QuoteId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PaymentOptionId { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

I have an interface there to send it to another layer which is my Infrastructure layer:

```
 public Task<bool> StoreConvertesCurrenciesAsync(List<ApiLayerViewModel> xyz);
```

I want to implement this in my Infrastructure layer,so Im going to create another class(exactly the same)there:

```
public class InfraLayerLayer
{
    public string QuoteId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PaymentOptionId { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

here i want to implement my interface,but cant because my interface expects the same model name i have put in my signature

```
 public class RepoInInfrstructureLayerIRepoInApiLayer: IRepoInApiLayer
{
    public Task<bool> StoreConvertesCurrenciesAsync(List<InfraLayerLayer> xyz) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: One layer would need to know about both models, and how to map between them.  Imagine you have API, Business and Repository layers.  IMO the Business layer would know about the Repository and Business models, and be able to map between them.  Then the API would only know about the business models (and API models if needed).

Comment: you mean since the  Infrastructure layer talks to business logic  we need can use the same model there as well by using the refence? @Jonesopolis

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that all of your functions, whether in the API or elsewhere use an interface type as input parameter rather than a concrete type.

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    string QuoteId { get; set; };
    string PaymentOptionId { get; set; };
}

public class ApiLayerViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public int APISpecificReference{get;set;}
    public string QuoteId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PaymentOptionId { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class InfraLayerViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public int InfraLayerSpecificReference{get;set;}
    public string QuoteId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PaymentOptionId { get; set; } = default!;
}

 public class RepoInInfrstructureLayerIRepoInApiLayer: IRepoInApiLayer
{
    public Task<bool> StoreConvertesCurrenciesAsync(List<IViewModel> xyz) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you can have something like:

```
IViewModel MapAPIToInfraLayer(IViewModel param)
{
    var result = new InfraLayerViewModel();
    result.QuoteId=param.QuoteId;
    result.PaymentOptionId=param.PaymentOptionId;
    result.InfraLayerSpecificReference = 0;//this layer specific data could be added
    return result;
}
```

I would point out though that if `QuoteId` and `PaymentOptionId` are index references that these be used to obtain the whole record for that index from the API so that you can map it against that required by the InfraLayer respository as over time these indexes may not match.